# Ubuntu 14.04.1 installation DVD cannot detect Win7, but the USB stick can

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-7, dvd

The same Ubuntu 14.04.1 ISO image is burned into a DVD disc and a USB stick.
The hard disk is of 1T bytes.
Win7 occupies the first 600G of the disk, and I'd like to install Ubuntu on the rest 400G.
It is surprised to find out that the DVD installation fails to detect win7, however, the USB stick installation succeeds.

Note that this DVD disc has been used to install along with win7 successfully before, but the installation was done on a 500G hard disk.

Comment: When you say it doesn't detect it, do you mean that it does not give the "Install along side of ..." option ?

Comment: Right, it does not show "Install along side of ..."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using such methods, try using the manual method. Its hard to understand first, but allows a lot more configurability like setting a custom space for a separate swap space(Which is important if you run out of RAM, and if you plan for using Hibernation).

Plus, mount points for specific folders can also be defined.

Additionally, the point of your question is kind of unclear, ie. its hard to understand what you are asking. Please be precise at what you want.

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu on my disk. I just doubt that there might be a bug in the installation process.

Comment: @Howardz Which bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is very probably a damaged DVD.  (scratch) If you *really* need a DVD, just burn the ISO file onto a new DVD disk or continue using the USB stick.

**Note to the low quality reviewers:** *Yeah, that's it!* :P